# After I publish a post where does it go

Tags: publish

I did not set up my Wordpress blog. So I don't really know how to use Wordpress. I got an email from godaddy saying I am using to much space. I can delete a lot of post. I just don't know where to delete them from. Should I delete them from my Wordpress site or my C Panle in godaddy. Where do the files go after I publish a post. Any help is appreciated. 
Scott

Comment: No specification as to where that space is used? If your run your own domain the primary suspect is a mail spam folder that does not get cleaned automatically (so no Wordpress at all).

Comment: And if it is Wordpress taking up the space, I'm almost sure that there is some plugin that tells you where that comes from: comments, posts, media,....

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the posts from your wordpress site, but you are likely going to want to look at the media section of your wp site, as if you have many videos or photos on your site, those will take more space than just a post. When in your wp admin panel, on the left you should see a nav menu with one option being media. Delete what you don't need out of there and see if it frees up the space you need. The posts will go into the wp database, so it's better to delete them out from wp itself rather than editing the database.

Comment: Unless the message specifically states that the database is too large, running out of space is usually a reference to file uploads. You can delete all of the posts and it may not help - definitely checkout your media library